# Reaching the Catch Block with an in-memory approach

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, xunit, in-memory-database

I have a TestController class where I'm performing unit tests on a Controller class.

The Controller class creates an instance of a Service class named `_service`. The Controller class has a method with the following implementation:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        try
        {
            return Ok(await _service.GetAll(ct));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e.Message);
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "There was an error processing your request.");
        }
    }
```

In my TestController class I create a Moq'ed instance of the Service class named `_mockService`. One of the methods in the TestController class uses `_mockService` and sets it up to throw an exception so I can test the return statement in the catch block of the Controller class:

```
    [Fact]
    public async void Get_ReturnsIActionResult_InternalServerError()
    {
        // Setup mock
        CancellationToken ct = default(CancellationToken);
        _mockService.Setup(ms => ms.GetAll(ct)).Throws(new TaskCanceledException());

        // Test class
        var result = await _controller.Get(ct);

        // Assert results
        var objectResult = Assert.IsType<ObjectResult>(result);
        Assert.Equal(500, objectResult.StatusCode);
    }
```

Similarly, I have a TestRepository class where I'm performing unit tests on a Repository class.

The Repository class creates an instance of a DbContext class named `_dbContext`. The Repository class has a method with the following implementation:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<SomeDbSetProperty>> GetAll(CancellationToken ct = default)
    {
        try
        {
            return await _dbContext.SomeDbSetProperty.Where(p => p.IsActivated == true).ToListAsync(ct);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Error in GetAll: {e}");
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Rather than Moq'ing the DbContext class (which would be a similar approach to how we Moq'ed the Service class in the TestController class), my team has opted to use an in-memory approach as outlined in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/testing-without-the-database#in-memory-provider). (I realize it's a discouraged approach, but the decision was not up to me.)

My goal is to create a test method in my TestRepository class that tests the code in the catch block of the Repository class (similarly to the method in my TestController class that tested the catch block in the Controller class).

My issue is that I can't figure out how to do that with the in-memory approach. It was easy to do with Moq by using the Setup and Throws methods, but I don't know of how to replicate that concept with the in-memory approach. Perhaps I'm experiencing why they don't recommend the in-memory approach, or perhaps, I'm overlooking something.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See my answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76876359/in-memory-db-not-supporting-defaultvalue-mapping-in-unit-testing/76880019#76880019

Basically the purpose of the Repository is to serve as that boundary where you can substitute with a Mock. In your case, if you are using an anemic controller (passing through to a service) then there is no need to mock the Service to test the controller, just test the service and mock the Repository which should be a thin wrapper around EF. Testing anemic code validates nothing, no business logic is happening here.

Comment: Thanks @StevePy. I spoke to the team and we're going to go a different direction for now, but I will keep your response in mind if we come back to in-memory testing.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options as I see it:

- Talk it through with your team and use in-memory for tests except for those that require controlled DB failure simulations. If the code is going to throw anyway, why would you even need in-memory? You get none of the benefits of avoiding complicated mocks.
- Add [custom interceptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors) to the DbContext during tests to simulate this behavior. It's going to be a bit ugly, but you can make specific database commands fail through them. You can sort of simulate a partial mock.
- Finally, don't do this logic within repository methods. You don't need these tests if there's no error-handling to begin with. You can put this logic somewhere else that won't require an in-memory DB and reduce repetitive boilerplate wrapping around your repo methods. There's countless options here, from abstract base repository classes to controller filters. You get to avoid repetitive exception tests for every single repo method.

Comment: Thanks! I spoke to the team this morning and we opted to go a different direction, but I will keep your response in mind if we come back to the in-memory approach.